# How to transfer received amount while paying gas from another account?

Tags: ether, smart-contract-wallets, bsc, smart-contract

Here's an example: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xe253f721338acde5c7b29eec16ea121396fc9ccc7d2fd79317db1de54bf7ecaf

I have sent 0.00950688 BNB to 0x86a54685774b674c848824b1ba3303418d0c3f80 address and the received amount is transferred **as-is** automatically to another address, i don't see who paid the gas ? how can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple smart contract you can easily transfer the ether entering into the smart contract to the account you want. In that case the ether sender will pay the gas fee.

In case of the above transaction wallet address `0x919921b9dde914ce2ab2211c4915a8574f69c389` has sent some BNB to the contract and the contract is auto sending the same bnb to `tip.cc` address. The code the smart contract should be using is similar to the code below.

```
......
address payable receiver = 0x820f92c1B3aD8E962E6C6D9d7CaF2a550Aec46fB;

receive() external payable {
  (bool success, ) = receiver.call{value: msg.value}();
  require(success)
}
......
```

So whatever value is entering into the smart contract is being directed to `0x820f92c1B3aD8E962E6C6D9d7CaF2a550Aec46fB (tip.cc)` address. Address `0x919921b9dde914ce2ab2211c4915a8574f69c389` is paying the gas fee.

Answer (score 0):

always the transaction initiator pays the gas of all calls included in the transaction. If you call a contract and the contract does 10 calls. You will pay for the all.

In the above example the `msg.sender` paying the fees is `0x919921B9Dde914cE2Ab2211c4915A8574F69c389`
Hope it helps

Comment: Do you have an example of such a contract source code ?